# '80s movie where a woman is chased and assaulted by an alien/humanoid/monster

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

All I can remember is watching this movie when I was younger and a specific scene.

A woman is being chased by alien/humanoid/monster in a dark underground parkade. The monster gets her and shoves his tongue down her throat; it basically goes all through her body?

It's not *Humanoids from the Deep*.

Comment: U.S.? U.K.? European? English language?  T.V. movie? In the cinema?  Colour?

Answer (score 9):

"[Scared To Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scared_to_Death_(1981_film))" (1980)?

This was a low budget sci-fi monster movie with a few similarities to Ridley Scott's "Alien" (1979),which was released the year before, including the bio-mechanical design of the monster and it's tongue-like organ which was not used for rape, but was used to extract the spinal fluid of it's victims. The creature was known as Syngenor which was short for SYNthesized GENetic ORganism. The creature was created in a lab, escapes, and hides beneath the streets of Los Angeles in sewers and parking garages. Below is the full movie from YouTube where you can see the scene you seem to be describing at 45:40 of the video.

Comment: I get all my best recommendations from this tag.

Answer (score 4):

[Xtro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xtro) (82) has an alien rape scene, followed by the woman giving birth to a full grown man.  Creepy as anything.

Comment: Video is unavailable. Based on the description, I'm not really sure we want it back